# Django rest model m2m sequentially store

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model *Task* and I want to create another model *Sequence* which will hold ordered sequence of tasks e.g. sequence1 -> Task1, Task3, Task 7 ; sequence2 -> Task1, Task2, Task4, Task7 etc.

A *sequence* can have many *Tasks* and  a *task* can be in multiple sequences.

How to create such a model to make sure it holds ordered sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model with M2M field relation. Then you can create a Serializer. In the serializer, you have some options to format your data from your M2M field:

i.e  **StringRelatedField**

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

Do this:

```
{
    'album_name': 'Things We Lost In The Fire',
    'artist': 'Low',
    'tracks': [
        '1: Sunflower',
        '2: Whitetail',
        '3: Dinosaur Act',
        ...
    ]
}
```

Or **PrimartKeyRelatedField**

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

Do This:

```
{
    'album_name': 'Undun',
    'artist': 'The Roots',
    'tracks': [
        89,
        90,
        91,
        ...
    ]
}
```

And more options. For more [read the Docs DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) .

PD: The data in M2M field is presented ordered by how your objects was created, by default